# Cucumber, Capybara, and Selenium check if browser alert is showing

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am looking for checking browser alert when I do a test case. In my scenario, if there is an error occurence, it will alert an pop up dialog. I was looking the solution to handle this. So far I have done a function like this :

```
def alert_present?
  begin
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
    true
  rescue
    Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertOpenError
    false
  end
end
```

is there any way other than this?

Answer (score 0):

ok so if you want just to accept the alert and you are not sure that even there will be one
then i think overriding the confirm method in javascript will do it, just make sure add this line before the line that triggers the dialogue to pop up

```
page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
your line of code that triggers the alert
```

if there will be alert it will be accepted once it popup if not there won't be problems.

Comment: in my case, the alert will only show when the user input is false. for example when the user type -1 on input form, it will alert an error message, but when user type number more than 0, it will not alert an error. I tried this once, when the alert does not appear, this produce selenium error